# Customizing the nano editor in google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I was wondering if there was a way to customize the nano editor settings in the Debian-based virtual machine instance when you launch the cloud shell.

I already tried going to the root of the instance then cd to etc and editing the nanorc file. but every time i try re-save the nanorc back it says permission denied.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize your `nano` editor settings by creating `$HOME/.nanorc` file.  While Google Cloud Shell virtual machines are ephemeral (the VM is turned down when idle and a new one is allocated when you are back), the content of your home disk is persistent.